# Antd modal doesn't react on custom hook state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a custom hook for managing the state of modal, I'm also passing the `showModal` and `toggleModal` down via context. The `MainModal` component receives the content and render it using `props.children`

Simplified demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions64212090-modal-antd-xptfv

useMainModal hook

```js
export const useMainModal = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<{ modalName: EntryModalEnum; visible: boolean }>({
    modalName: EntryModalEnum.deleteEntry,
    visible: false,
  });
  const [newsId, setNewsId] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);

  const toggleModal = (type: EntryModalEnum) => {
    setShowModal({ modalName: type, visible: !showModal.visible });
  };

  const setId = (id: number) => {
    setNewsId(id);
  };

  return {
    showModal,
    toggleModal,
    newsId,
    setId,
  };
};
```

MainModal.tsx generic modal, that receives content and render current modal. `EntryModal` or `DeleteModal`. The `Styled.Modal` is an `antd` `Modal` component

```js
export const MainModal = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const modalRoot = document.querySelector('#modal-root');
  const { showModal } = useMainModal();

  if (!modalRoot) {
    return null;
  }

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <Styled.Modal visible={showModal.visible} footer={null} destroyOnClose={true}>
      {children}
    </Styled.Modal>,
    modalRoot,
  );
};
```

I would like to render modals like this in homepage, using generic MainModal component.

```js
<MainModal>
  <EntryModal />
</MainModal>

<MainModal>
  <DeleteModal />
</MainModal>
```